# Permute array to make it alternate between increasing and decreasing

Tags: arrays, algorithm

> An array X[1..n] of distinct integers is ***wobbly*** if it alternates between increasing and decreasing: X[i] < X[i+1] for every odd index *i*, and X[i] > X[i+1] for every even index *i*. For example, the following 16-element array is wobbly:

12, 13, 0, 16, 13, 31, 5, 7, -1, 23, 8, 10, -4, 37, 17, 42

> Describe and analyze an algorithm that permutes the elements of a given array to make the array wobbly.

My attempt:

The more obvious solution that comes to mind would be to sort the original array, split it in half, and then alternate between each sub-array, grabbing the first element in the array to create the wobbly array. This would take O(nlogn). (Edit: Just realized this would only work if all of the integers are distinct.) I cant help but think there is a more efficient way to achieve this.

How could this be done?

(This is not a homework problem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[After 3 years... :-)]

Your problem definition states that all the array elements are distinct. So, you can do better than sorting -- sorting does too much.

Consider that you have a ***wobbly*** sequence constructed out of the first `k` elements. There can be two cases for the last two elements in the sequence:

1. `A[k-1] < A[k]`
2. `A[k-1] > A[k]`

**Case 1**: if `A[k+1] < A[k]`, you don't have to do anything because ***wobbliness*** is already maintained. However, if `A[k+1] > A[k]`, swapping them will ensure wobbliness is restored.

**Case 2**: if `A[k+1] > A[k]`, you don't have to do anything because wobbliness is already maintained. However, if `A[k+1] < A[k]`, swapping them will ensure wobbliness is restored.

This gives you an `O(n)` time and `O(1)` space algorithm (because you are swapping in place). Your base case is when k = 2, which is trivially wobbly.

Following is an implementation in Python3:

```
def rearrange_wobbly(A):
    if len(A) < 3:
        return A
    for i in range(2, len(A)):
        if A[i - 2] < A[i - 1] < A[i] or A[i - 2] > A[i - 1] > A[i]:
            # Swap A[i] and A[i - 1]
            A[i - 1], A[i] = A[i], A[i - 1]

>>> A = [x for x in range(10)]
>>> A
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> random.shuffle(A)
>>> A
[3, 2, 1, 0, 7, 6, 9, 8, 4, 5]
>>> rearrange_wobbly(A)
>>> A
[3, 1, 2, 0, 7, 6, 9, 4, 8, 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

This most straight-forward approach I can think of is to sort the array and then alternate between taking the lowest and the highest remaining element.

E.g. with your example list, sorted:

```
-4 -1 0 5 7 8 10 12 13 13 16 17 23 31 37 42
```

The result then becomes

```
-4 42 -1 37 0 31 5 23 7 17 8 16 10 13 12 13
```

However, I think this breaks down if you have identical elements toward the middle, so in that scenario you might have to do a bit of manual value substitution towards the end of the sequence to restore the "wobbly" constraint.